# Update Manager failed to load Package List

Tags: updates, update-manager

Every time I run the update manager I see an error message:

> Failed to load the package list. This is a serious problem. Try again
>   later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the
>   developers.

Comment: off the top of my head: have you a) rebooted, b) are you online, c) you could change to a different download mirror.